# OSX 10.8.3 creating/editing files on Windows 7 share creates weird blocking account

Tags: windows, mac-osx, file-permissions, share

I have a share on a Windows 7 machine that acts as a server.  We have several people on Macs that need to create/modify files on this machine.  When one of these people creates a file on the share using a code editor, or updates a file using an SVN client (Versions) the file acquires a Windows account with a name like this:

**S-1-5-88-3-33216**

This account has no permissions and seems to mess with all the other permissions on the file.  The end result is that IIS can't serve up the file until I remove this account manually from the file permissions.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That SID [is interesting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee380665.aspx). It's used by Windows for UNIX translation, and that particular one is what stores the UNIX mode. The smbfs drivers for Apple [have this in a comment too](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/smb/smb-551/kernel/smbfs/smbfs_security.c). The 33216 number translates to the Mode of the file, or should since 33216 doesn't translate to a correct POSIX mode.

You can get around this by removing "Full Control" for "Everyone" at the share level (and possibly the NTFS level) and changing it to "Modify".

Comment: Whoa thanks!  Just a note:  It's "Everyone" on Windows 7.  I didn't have this user set at all.